# Всплывающее окно если запрос выполнен

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Нужно сделать следующее. 
Пользователь нажимает кнопку, по кнопке выполняется запрос в бд - если запрос выполнен - появляется модальное окно в котором говорится о том что запрос выполнен. 
Запрос простой - `$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM таблица WHERE id='$id'");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($sql!==false) {

//тут код модального окна
```

}

из доков: mysql_query() возвращает TRUE в случае успешного запроса и FALSE в случае ошибки